# Is cms/content.phtml ever used?

Tags: magento

Judging by the file structure you would think that a cms-page uses the content_heading.phtml file to print the heading and the content.phtml to print the content of the page, but apparently that's not the case.

Changes to content_heading.phtml come out just fine, but for content.phtml; nothing.

Is content.phtml ever used? If no, how would you go about changing or adding html around the content without using the wysiwyg in the admin?

Comment: Ok. So cms/block/Page.php skips the normal template approach, and handles the printing on its own. I hate this platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find a single reference in the framework to `cms/content.phtml`. It appears to be unused. CMS pages can be set to use different content templates at your request, most of which follow typical Magento page layouts.

Take a look [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates) for a tutorial on how to add a new CMS template, which you can change at will.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe